# CakePHP updating issue (duplicate entry)

Tags: php, cakephp

I having trouble updating multiple fields in cake php.

this is $product

```
array(
'sku' => '45',
'name' => 'fefefef22',
'short_description' => '99',
'long_description' => '33',
'price' => '444',
'special_price' => '444',
'stock' => '444',
'brand' => '4',
'is_promo' => '0'
```

)

```
my controller
public function update($sku)
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->layout = false;
    if($this->request->data) {
        $this->Product->sku = $sku;
        $product = $this->request->data['Product'];
        $this->Product->save($product);
    }
}
```

The error message

1062 Duplicate entry '45' for key 'PRIMARY';

i have tryed lots of other action but still the same message.

thx

Comment: Have you checked your table entries into db ? this error comes because 45 already exist into your table

Comment: try to remove 'sku' from $this->request->data

Comment: I did, its still keeps try to insert new entry instead of updating the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$this->Product->sku = $sku;
```

To this:

```
$this->Product->id = $sku;
```

The `->id` part is not setting a field named "id" - it's setting the primary key.  So in your case, setting the `->id` to `$sku`, is actually telling it that you want the value of the field "sku" to be that value.

The model has no idea what you're trying to set when you use `->sku`.

`->id` is referring to `$id` in the model as seen in the code in `Model.php` of CakePHP:

```
/**
 * Value of the primary key ID of the record that this model is
 * currently pointing to.
 * Automatically set after database insertions.
 *
 * @var mixed
 */
public $id = false;
```

This is all assuming that you correctly set the primaryKey in the model per the [book's example](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#primarykey):

```
public $primaryKey = 'sku';
```

Comment: I would recommend doing `echo $this->Form->input('sku');` in your View as well. If Cake knows `sku` is your primary key then the field will be hidden, and will already be included in your `$request->data`

Comment: @iso27002 - Certainly not a problem to do that, but we don't know the original intent for why he was setting `$sku` in the URL, so it's hard to suggest that and isn't really related to the problem he's asking about.